# Introduction to discrete mathematics reference request

Tags: discrete-mathematics, reference-request

I am going to take a course in Combinatorics next semester, my very first one and I am looking for some good book to learn from. The topics that will be covered, as quoted from a syllabus, are:

1. Counting (basics, double counting, Pigeonhole Principle, recursions, generating functions, Inclusion-Exclusion, inversion, Polya theory)
2. Discrete Structures (graphs, set systems, designs, posets, matroids)
3. Graph Theory (trees, matchings, connectivity, planarity, colorings)
4. Algorithms (asymptotic running time, BFS, DFS, Dijkstra, Greedy, Kruskal, Hungarian, Ford-Fulkerson)

So far I have stumbled upon [An Invitation to Discrete Mathematics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0198570422) by Jiří Matoušek and Jaroslav Nešetřil.

I have not yet looked through the book, but I was simply curious if anyone can advise me any resource from his own experience. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend this book highly:

[http://www.amazon.com/Concrete-Mathematics-Foundation-Computer-Science/dp/0201558025](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201558025)

Answer (score 1):

Two introductory texts are:

Discrete Mathematics and its Applications, by Kenneth Rosen.

Discrete Mathematics, by Norman Biggs.